# Django does not create a model instance every single time from Views

Tags: python, django

I basically have two models, `Person` and `Profiles` which have a OneToOne relationship with each other. The `Profiles` models consists of a set of `BooleanFields` which indicate whether the `Person` has social media profiles.

```
#models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    address = models.TextField()
    dob = models.DateField()

class Profiles(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profiles')
    fb = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    twitter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    insta = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    linkedin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now, as soon as a `Person` model instance is created, I want to create a corresponding `Profiles` model instance. Towards this end, in the `views.py` file, as soon as the form with the `Person` attributes is created, I instantiate a `Profiles` class with the `person` being the just created instance. Like below:

```
#views.py

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonUploadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            prof = Profiles(person=instance)
            prof.save()
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'template.html', context)
    else:
         form = PersonUploadForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Now the issue, I'm facing is that `prof = Profiles(person=instance)` and `prof.save()` don't work 100% of the time. I know this because `Person` and `Profiles` models don't have the same number of objects when they theoretically should be the same. I am frankly surprised that this is happening because the `save()` call is happening in the normal control flow of the view function and there isn't any error being thrown up at runtime.

What is happening here and how do I fix this? I apologize if the question isn't worded properly

Comment: Is it possible that you created users for example through the `createsuperuser` command? This will then not create a `Profile`.

Comment: That being said, I don't really see why you need a `Person` and `Profile` model in the first place. Why not save all the data in a *single* model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not creating users at all let alone through the `createsuperuser` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to use django signals:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def create_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    prof = Profiles()
    prof.person = instance
    prof.save()
```

Comment: I was using signals till recently but I looked up a few places where they said that it isn't good practice to use signals for actions that might have some effect on another model. That's when I tried to bring back the `Profiles` creation back into the view.
I would upvote the score of this answer but I don't have sufficient reputation. I'll accept this as the answer if nobody can offer any other suggestions as to why the instantiation might not be happening.